# How to model those stylized trunks (See image)

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves, subdivision-surface

Currently trying to do some stylized trees; i am struggling to do those trunks.
Tried some subdivision surface but I can't make the corners nice at 90°

I bet there's a nicer way to do it; maybe with curves or so ? But i would like to keep the subdivision surface (and maybe make the loop smaller and smaller toward the ends of branch)

Any Drupal Guru out there to help me out ?

Thanks !

[image]

Comment: Is "Drupal" what people are calling "Blender" these days? If so, it's about time Drupal CMS lost its name to something else. I've been calling Drupal "Disaster" for years

Comment: Hahaha right; when you have sooo many windows open ... mixing things up :) 
Thx for pointing it out; i'll leave it as a proof that i am waaay too much committed

Comment: When somebody asks why recruiters for Drupal jobs are looking for people with Blender experience I'm pointing @DiscoFever.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the best way to achieve trees with branches is to make use of the Skin Modifier.

Begin by enabling a couple of add-ons ("Extra Objects"), if they're not already enabled.

[image: Tree1]

This will give you the ability to add a single vert from the mesh menu.

[image: Tree2]

Add a vertex, and give it a Skin Modifier.

[image: Tree3]

You can extrude points by selecting them and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Right Click</kbd> somewhere else (where you want to extrude it to). You can then scale the individual points using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>.

[image: Tree4]

You can also reselect individual points and extrude them elsewhere to make multiple "branches"

[image: Tree5]

Once you have the tree shape you like, you can add a Subdivision Surface Modifier to make it smooth and round.

[image: Tree6]

The best thing about this method, I find, is that it makes proper "knuckles" where the different branches connect to each other.

Answer (score 8):

There are multiple relatively easy ways to achieve this.

**Manual modelling**

Start by adding a circle. `Shift` + `a` -> `Mesh` -> `Circle`

Use the menu on the bottom left to set the vertex count (8 is fine, we can subdivide later) and the radius.

[image]

press `tab` to switch to edit mode. make sure you select all vertices, and extrude them upwards.

[image]

position the 3d cursor at the center of the desired radius. you can either `shift` + `rmb` or position it via the n-panel on the left.

[image]

press `space` and type in "spin".

[image]

with this, we extrude and rotate the selected vertices with the 3d cursor as center of rotation. In this step you can also adjust the segments. (you have to adjust my settings to suit your setup and angle of rotation.)

[image]

Just repeat the steps extruding and spinning in the other direction and you're done.

Use "shade smooth" and subdivision modifier to get smoother results.

[image]

**Curves**

Add a bezier curve. Use `e`to extrude new segments and `r` to rotate them to get a shape you like.

[image]

Use the properties panel to bevel the curves and adjust the resolution.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with curves but you can also do it with meshes.

Select your circles before and after a corner and link them with Bridge Edge Loops:

[image]

Then tweak the settings, especially Number of Cuts and Smoothness:

[image]